# WIX Fetch API returns empty JSON (VELO)

Tags: javascript, fetch, velo, agile-crm

### Overview

I am using AgileCRM. I would like to create new contacts in this CRM when users complete a form. I have been successful in doing just that within PostMan. I am trying to do a simple "GET" request from WIX so I can understand VELO code before I get into my POST request (create contacts).

### Problem

When I make `GET` request I get a status of `200`, I get an empty JSON as a response and in my request header is says my method is a **`POST`** which is not what I defined as the method.

### Question

What is it that I am doing wrong here that is causing both an empty response and incorrect method?

### Setup

My front-end imports a backend function which handles the basic auth and fetching. I did it this way as when I did this from the front-end I got a CORS issue.

```
//agileapi.jsw
import {fetch} from 'wix-fetch';
import base64 from "nodejs-base64-encode";
import {getSecret} from 'wix-secrets-backend';

export async function getAPIKey() {
  return await getSecret("AGILERESTAPI");
}

export async function getUsername() {
  return await getSecret("AGILEUSERNAME");
}

let password = getAPIKey()
let username = getUsername()

let options = {
    "method": "GET",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": 'Basic ' + base64.encode(username + ":" + password, 'base64'),
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }
}
let url = "https://photodynamic.agilecrm.com/dev/api/contacts";
export async function getContacts() {
   await fetch(url, options)
    .then( (response) => {
        if(response.ok) {
            return response.json()
        }
        else {
            return Promise.reject('Fetch did not succeed');
        }}
    )
    .then((json) => console.log(json))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}

//wix debug page code
import {getContacts} from 'backend/agileapi'

$w.onReady(function (){
   $w("#getContacts").onClick( (event) => {
        getContacts()
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait until the promises are fulfilled. The **password** and **username** in your code it's not a string it's a Promise.

```
//agileapi.jsw
import { fetch } from 'wix-fetch';
import base64 from "nodejs-base64-encode";
import { getSecret } from 'wix-secrets-backend';

const url = "https://photodynamic.agilecrm.com/dev/api/contacts";

export async function getContacts() {
  // Wait for until all promises to be fulfilled
  const [password, username] = await Promise.all([
    getSecret("AGILERESTAPI"),
    getSecret("AGILEUSERNAME")
  ])

  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      // Now the password and username are the strings
      "Authorization": 'Basic ' + base64.encode(username + ":" + password, 'base64'),
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }
  }

  // Returns the API result to client (browser)
  return fetch(url, options)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      }
      return Promise.reject('Fetch did not succeed');
    });
}
```

**Page Code**

```
import { getContacts } from 'backend/agileapi'

$w.onReady(function () {
  $w("#getContacts").onClick((event) => {
    getContacts()
      .then((json) => {
        // Your json
        console.log(json);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Reason of error
        console.log(error)
      });
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this. The rest api returned xml by default. By adding the the following to my headers allowed me to get it formatted as JSON.

```
let options = {
"method": "GET",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": 'Basic ' + base64.encode(username + ":" + password, 'base64'),
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        // added this to resolve the issue
        "Accept": "application/json"
    }

}
```

This solution is specific to AgileCRM and may differ with the API you are using. Hopefully my above code will others trying to do API calls with WIX Velo.